# iterate over JRC Monthy water history on google earth engine using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

below is the sample code which retrive data from the folder and displays it What I trying to is to iterate over folder data i.e.  **JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory/*2020_06*** and display all the required data and download.I tried for loop but nothing worked well.

```
var dataset = ee.Image('JRC/GSW1_4/MonthlyHistory/2020_06');

var visualization = {
  bands: ['water'],
  min: 0.0,
  max: 2.0,
  palette: ['ffffff', 'fffcb8', '0905ff']
};

Map.setCenter(67.7792, 26.4236, 10);

Map.addLayer(dataset, visualization, 'Water');
```